Why do most languages have TAM inflection on verbs but not on pronouns?
Examples of languages with TAM inflection on pronouns: Hausa, Wolof
It is quite a rare feature but we find it in English as well: eg. we'll eat. we've sung. Imma do it.
From the English examples above, TAMs attach to pronouns very naturally as they are frequently right after the pronouns.
Perhaps TAMs have an extremely close relationship with verbs but not with pronouns?
Word order and degree of prefixing/suffixing definitely play an important role too. TAMs on SOV languages would look like German:
Ich-werde den Apfel (und so weiter) essen
As if it results in a long dependency length between werde-essen.
Is there any related research?

TAM are fundamentally verbal not nominal. They may appear to attach to English pronouns, but that's mostly a surface level phonological contraction, underneath it's still verbal.

Temporal divisions into past, present and future quite inherently apply more obviously to actions and states (≈ verbs) than to physical and abstract entities (≈ nominals, i.e., nouns and pronouns). Conversely, properties like number and possession inherently apply more obviously to entities than to actions/states, which is why we often see those categories on nominals and virtually never on verbs (excluding nominal forms like participles, and keeping in mind that verbal conjugation according to person/number marks the number of an associated nominal constituent, not of the verb itself).
